# Python won't print negative values when running from Windows cmd

Tags: python

I wrote a simple script in Python which rewrites hex values as their decimal *32-bit signed* counterpart.

```
data = [data.rstrip('\n') for data in open('dlzkyHEAD.txt')]

for value in data:
   print(value, end=' -> ')
   x= int(value,16)
   print(x) if x<2**31 else x-2**32
```

When running it in the Python shell everything was working. But when I wrote the same commands to a file and executed them from Windows cmd it wouldn't print the negative values.

*Python shell output:*

```
8049008 -> 134516744
80490c0 -> 134516928
80490d0 -> 134516944
80490d8 -> 134516952
8049d84 -> 134520196
8049d88 -> 134520200
8049da4 -> 134520228
c -> 12
ffffefe8 -> -4120
ffffffe0 -> -32
ffffffe4 -> -28
ffffffe8 -> -24
ffffffec -> -20
fffffff0 -> -16
fffffff4 -> -12
fffffffc -> -4
```

*cmd output:*

```
8049d88 -> 134520200
8049da4 -> 134520228
c -> 12
ffffefe8 -> ffffffe0 -> ffffffe4 -> ffffffe8 -> ffffffec -> fffffff0 -> fffffff4 -> fffffffc ->
```

Comment: how are you executing it? What do you mean "executed in windows cmd?" as opposed to "working in python shell"

Comment: I meant it like this:
C:\Users\User_Name\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\python.exe script.py

Comment: Did you mean `print(x if x<2**31 else x-2**32)`?

Comment: @cricket_007 The issue is exactly that. Python shell outputs stuff that doesn't print too.

Comment: @AntonvBR Point being, the result is *calculated* and returned to the CLI, but not printed?

Comment: @cricket_007 Yeah, well I think we mean the same thing. Go ahead and post an answer if you want

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As we (thanks to @cricket_007 pointed out in comments this line here will only print if x<2**31:

```
print(x) if x<2**31 else x-2**32
```

You are interested in printing when else is executed too:

```
print(x if x<2**31 else x-2**32)
print(x) if x<2**31 else print(x-2**32)
```

Or

```
if x<2**31:
    print(x)
else:
    print(x-2**32)
```

Comment: Yes you are right, it is just weird that Python Shell printed it normaly. Thx for the help.